# Is there a way to delete unused fields?

Tags: entities, nodes, database

I created many fields for content type.Now I don't need these fields anymore. 
I deleted the fields from the content type but the fiels data remains in the database.

How can I delete the field and all its related data?

Comment: You need to run `cron` jobs to delete field permanently.

Comment: instances will be queued for deletion after the last instance deleted. delete them and run cron job.

Comment: Have a look through the posts in [this search](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=field_purge_batch)

Comment: @Clive thanks. Do you mind to move your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes running cron does not entirely delete a field, especially if the field was ever used in a field collection. First, make sure the field isn't used anywhere else. Check all content types, field collections, custom user fields, etc. if the field is really not used but running cron does not delete the field table from the database, you may have to delete it manually. You can do this manually with a SQL query or via phpmyadmin.

Comment: Running `cron`should do the trick as Jayendra mentioned... you can do that manually, otherwise it should run periodically and then you would notice that eventually the data was no longer in the database.